# Does std::vector size()-1 ALWAYS give the index of the last element?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, indexing, push-back

Say I have a `std::vector` named `myVec`.

I don't know the exact size it will reach, so i use only `myVec.push_back(...)`.

Can I rely on the fact that after I have pushed_back, size()-1 will give me the index of that last element?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, *iff* you used `push_back`.

Comment: That is why for safety use the iterator, instead of using indexes to access elements in a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For non-empty vectors yes, `size()-1` is the index of the last element.

Comment: @arturn Not sure what is your point. After calling `resize(100)` the vector size is 100, and its last index is 99, which is also `size() - 1`.

Comment: @arturn In C++ null normally means null pointer, or 0 character ending C-style strings. Here we have a vector of int8_t, so talking about nulls may be misleading. The vector after resize will have all elements of the default value zero.

Answer (score 7):

You have two separate questions. In the title you ask:

> Does std::vector size()-1 ALWAYS give the index of the last element?

No. It does not give the index of the last element if the vector is empty.

> Can I rely on the fact that after I have pushed_back, size()-1 will give me the index of that last element?

Yes, if the vector is not empty, then `size() - 1` is guaranteed to be the index of the last element.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out... I meant only on non-empty vectors and after push_backs, but I can see how the question can be misleading.